# Spring webflux webfilter forward request external application

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working on springboot webflux application. I want to filter the incoming request to my application and based on some logic I want to forward the request to another application(from server only) with all the header and request payload.

I already tried response.getHeaders().setLocation(mutatedURL). but this will be client based redirection that is not the requirement.

Comment: Thats the point of 301, you are telling your client where to go.

Comment: @VovaBilyachat: You are correct. Updated the question with the requirement.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look into my answer:?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want to do is that if request comin in you are checking some thing and based on some rules you allow to continue or you call some external URL and return result back to the client

```
package com.vob.webflux.webfilter.filter;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@Component
public class ProxyFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public ProxyFilter() {
        this.webClient = WebClient.create("https://stackoverflow.com");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        var goToOtherAddress = false; // replace this to be your logic which will determine where request go
        return goToOtherAddress
                ? requestOtherWebsite(exchange.getRequest()).flatMap(body -> writeResponse(exchange, body)) // this will return result from external server
                : chain.filter(exchange); // This will allow request to reach your controller
    }

    public Mono<String> requestOtherWebsite(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        return this.webClient.get().uri("/someurlhere")
                .headers(httpHeaders -> {

                    for (var header : request.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
                        // TODO make it how you want
                        httpHeaders.set(header.getKey(), header.getValue().get(0));
                    }
                })
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
    }


    private Mono<Void> writeResponse(ServerWebExchange exchange, String message) {
        exchange.getResponse().setRawStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return exchange
                .getResponse()
                .writeWith(
                        Flux.just(
                                exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved this by using spring cloud gateway route